# Возможно ли ввести ограничение на наследование классов?

Tags: c++, наследование

Есть следующая структура наследования:

```
class Parent;

class Child1: public Parent;
class Child2: public Parent;

class GrandChild: public Child1;

vector<Parent*> V{};
```

Вектор V может содержать указатели на экземпляр любого из этого классов. Но возможно ли запретить использование класса GrandChild? Т.е. вектор V мог бы содержать только Child1*, Child2* (Parent*).

Comment: отнаследоваться приватно? `class GrandChild: private Child1;`

Comment: @KoVadim, действительно... а весь интерфейс public Parent'a будет доступен в GrandChild? Еще не использовал такой вид наследования, и почему то думал, что закроется весь наследуемый интерфейс

Comment: да, с дочернего класса будет доступ к всем публичным данным родительского. Можно и protected наследование использовать, тогда будет доступ и к protected данным.

Comment: все, разобрался. Сделал protected, а то, что нужно добавил в GrandChild - using Child1::someMetod;. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

вам надо, чтобы компилятор ругался?

поскольку везде используется указатель и в векторе при приведении типов можно хранить хоть указатель на int, типа

```
val = 0;
V.push_back((Parent*)&val);
```

можно сделать извратно -

1. создать специальный класс-оболочку `Guard`, который будет содержать ссылку на `Parent`
2. вектор должен хранить именно этот класс, а не указатель

   ```
    vector<Guard> V;
   ```
3. в конструкторе класса или в методе `set` делать проверку - какой тип передаваемого объекта и отсекать всё, что не `Child1`, `Child2` или `Parent`

типа так:

```
Child1 obj1;
GrandChild obj2

vector<Guard> V;
V.push_back(Guard(obj1)); // сработает
V.push_back(Guard(obj2)); // не сработает, компилятор ругнется
```

Comment: да, про класс-оболочку - мысль первая пришла... Но как то сложно - и сколько мест править придется. Ответ  @KoVadim вроде то, что нужно ;)